# d3.drag(): initialize a variable on "start" and use it on "drag" and "end"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a code similar to the one below:

```
    var dragme = d3.drag()
        .on("start", function (d) {
           var variable1 =   // complex calucaltion result;
        })
        .on("drag", function (d) {
            //do something with variable1 without repeating the complex calculation 
        })
        .on("end", function (d) {
            //access variable1 again without repeat calculation
        });
```

How can this be achieved without extending `variable1` out of the drag()'s context?

UPDATE: The function call is as follows:

```
d3.select("#container").call(dragme); //#container is a svg group
```

Comment: Can u provide a JSFiddle? which version of d3 are u using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
var dragme = d3.drag()
        .on("start", function (d) {
           var variable1 = d3.select(this).attr("x");
           //do some heavy calculation and store in variable
           var calculation = 12354;
           //store it in the data model.
           d.calculation = calculation; 
        })
        .on("drag", function (d) {
          //do something with d.calculation
        })
        .on("end", function (d) {
          //do something with d.calculation    
        });
```

Since you don't have a data this is the not so good  way:

```
var dragme = d3.drag()
        .on("start", function (d) {
           var variable1 = d3.select(this).attr("x");
           //do some heavy calculation and store in variable
           var calculation = 12354;
           //store it in the data model.
           d3.select(this)[0][0].my_data = 1234;
        })
        .on("drag", function (d) {
          var calculation = d3.select(this)[0][0].my_data;
          //do something with calculation
        })
        .on("end", function (d) {
          var calculation = d3.select(this)[0][0].my_data;
          //do something with calculation    
        });
```

Comment: I used `attr("x")` as a simple example, in the actual scenario, I was hoping to set the result of a complex calculation on variable1 and use the result without recalculating.

Comment: Hi I updated the question a bit with more details. What if I want to use it again on "end"? Calculate again?

Comment: Then to call it as `d.v`? I get "TypeError: d is undefined". To be clear, I updated the question with which calls the function

Comment: huh! so u have not set any data to the node you are dragging.:(

Comment: Should I? Well, there is no data. I just want the container to be dragged and it works fine - if I keep repeating the calculations. I just wanted to find a way to reduce repetition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123832/discussion-between-cyril-and-sachdan).

Comment: For some reason `d3.select(this)["_groups"][0][0].my_data` worked :)

Comment: I don't really know why but it is not working again. Is there any limitations for this kind of assignment?

Comment: Nopes there is no limitations, to such assignments..I was surprised when you doing`d3.select(this)["_groups"][0][0].my_data` coz I dont know from _groups have come...but you should be able to console log debug and get around it